# How to put a relative link to main domain home page from subdomain home page

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a subdomain file - subcomain.maindomain.com/index.php
The subdomain folder is in the public_html folder 
I would like to put a link which will go to the main domain index page.

I want to put

```
  <a href="../index.php">Return to Main Domain homepage</a>
```

The desired result should be http://maindomain/index.php but instead I get http://subdomain/index.php

How can I do this correctly with a relative path and not an absolute path or a http url in the href ? Any other way to do this besides href ?

I searched everywhere but the questions on this topic have no good answer, so asked it.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Use a URL, not a path. Reason: to a http client a "subdomain" and a "domain" have _nothing_ to do with each other.

Comment: I dont think this is possible, the path in the HREF isnt (and more importantly should never be) related to the actual full path of the files in the hard disk.

You may define the main domain url as a constant and just echo it whenever you need to link to it.

Comment: @versvs arkascha Any other way to do this besides href ?